# decimal to excess-3 and aiken converter

Tags: java

Excess-3: Made by Arvind Kumar Avinash

```
 String yaz = "123";
        
        String binary = 
                Arrays.stream(yaz.split(""))
                        .map(x -> String.format("%4s", Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(x) + 3)).replace(' ', '0'))
                        .collect(Collectors.joining());

        System.out.println(binary);
```

I'm not sure if the stream.of operation used is correct.
My action here is; I add 3 to each digit of the decimal data I receive from the user and convert it to a 2-digit system. In other words, 457 => 4,5,7 =(3 + 3 +3) 7,8,10 => We convert the number 7 to a 2-number system, in the same way, 8 and 10 the result It should be like (457) = (0111 1000 1010).

aiken code: Made by Alex Rudenko

```
int input = 468;
String[] aiken = Integer.toString(input).chars()
    .map(Character::getNumericValue)
    .mapToObj(d -> String.format("%4s", 
        Integer.toBinaryString(d + (d > 4 ? 6 : 0))) // get aiken value
        .replace(' ', '0') // provide 0 padding
    )
    .toArray(String[]::new);
System.out.println(input + " -> " + Arrays.toString(aiken));
```

I thank both of you

Comment: for aiken it would be something like `if (n > 4) n = n+6`. Note that it only encodes numbers up to 9

Answer (score 2):

The requested conversion of a single digit to a binary representation with leading zeros should be implemented with a prepared array of Strings:

```java
static final String[] DIGITS = {
    "0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111",
    "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011", "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111"
};
```

Then [Excess-3 code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excess-3) can be built by converting the input number to String, using `Character::getNumericValue` for each character and shifting the value by 3:

```java
int input = 123;
String[] excess3 = Integer.toString(input).chars()
    .map(Character::getNumericValue)
    .mapToObj(i -> DIGITS[i + 3])
    .toArray(String[]::new);
System.out.printf("xcs-3(%d) -> %s%n", input, String.join(" ", excess3));
```

Output:

```
xcs-3(123) -> 0100 0101 0110
```

---

According to Wiki [Aiken code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aiken_code) is something different and it adds 6 to the digits over 4 (5 -> 0xB,.. 9 -> 0xF).
Thus, to convert *separate* digits to their Aiken codes and print it as 4-digit binary numbers, the following code may be used:

```java
int input = 468;
String[] aiken = Integer.toString(input).chars()
    .map(Character::getNumericValue)
    .mapToObj(d -> DIGITS[d > 4 && d <= 9? d + 6 : d])
    .toArray(String[]::new);
System.out.printf("aiken(%d) -> %s%n", input, String.join(" ", aiken));
```

Output

```
aiken(468) -> 0100 1100 1110
```

Comment: How can we print the values ​​in the array list to JtextField?

Comment: It may be preferable to use `String::join` method to get rid of the brackets provided by `Arrays.toString`, for example: `jtextField.setText(String.join(" ", aiken))` will print the numbers divided by a single space.

Answer (score 1):

1. Split the integer string into digits using `String#split`.
2. Get a stream out of the resulting array using `Arrays#stream`.
3. Use `Stream#map` to add `3` to each digit, parsed into an integer, and then convert the obtained integer to a binary string using  `Integer#toBinaryString` which you can format to occupy a space required for 4 characters and replace the empty places at the beginning of it with `0`.
4. Finally, join all elements of the stream.

Now, you can set the final string (`binary` in the code given below) to the `JTexField`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String yaz = "123";

        String binary = Arrays.stream(yaz.split(""))
                .map(x -> String.format("%4s", Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(x) + 3)).replace(' ', '0'))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

        System.out.println(binary);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0100 0101 0110
```

**Note:** if you do not need space between the binary strings, use the non-parametrized variant of [`Collectors#joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining--) i.e. do not pass the argument, `" "` to it.

### Alternatively,

You can use [`String#chars`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#chars--), introduced as part of Java SE 9, to create the stream. Note that it returns an `IntStream` which needs to be [`boxed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed--) to get `Stream<Integer>`.

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String yaz = "123";
        
        String binary = yaz.chars()
                            .boxed()
                            .map(x -> String.format("%4s", Integer.toBinaryString(Character.getNumericValue(x) + 3)).replace(' ', '0'))
                            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
        
        System.out.println(binary);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0100 0101 0110
```

Comment: yes, but our goal is not to make 123 126, but our goal is to make 123 456 and write 456 as binary, while converting to excess-3, it was explained that this would be done.

Comment: thank you so much. Some applications on the Internet (123) 10 = (010001010110) I see that the XS3 value is output, I get the output of 111001000 as a result of your help, I wonder where it is missing

Comment: I am so sorry,
It was necessary to convert the numbers 4 5 6 to a four-bit binary number system.
I don't know how I skipped this detail, I'm so sorry

Comment: How can I convert a user-entered value to a 3,4,8 bit binary?
for example how can I find 3,4,8 bit values ​​of 1,25

Comment: @Atlas - I didn't understand this new requirement. Do you want to find the 3rd, 4th, and 8th bit of 125?

Comment: 1.25 in float or double type => 3,4,8-bit binary number system value